# I just sent bitcoin to my bitcoin cash wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I just sent bitcoin to my bitcoin cash wallet.  I’m using blockchain and Coinbase and all the reading I’ve been doing it doesn’t appear there is anything I can do about this. I’ve tried getting ahold of Coinbase to see if they can help and I’m just put on hold forever. Can someone please help   Thanks

Comment: Only thing you can do is wait for coinbase support, they're the only ones who can access the private keys needed for the recovery

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a problem... I just asked my son for his bitcoin wallet key (btc) and also for his bitcoin cash wallet key (bch) and also for a few other of his wallet keys (ETH, LTC etc) so that I could send him a small amount of each for his Christmas present... I then noticed that his key for btc was exactly the same as his bch key so I asked him to check, he checked and assured me that they did in fact both have exactly the same key so it seems that one wallet can hold both btc and bch coins... I hope this helps... Best Wishes.